# How to export interactive PDF for iOs?

Tags: ios, pdf, interactive

I have an interactive PDF, a catalog, where you have to click on a image to go to a specific page. All images are converted in buttons with the option "Go to destination". On Windows and Mac it works perfectly. But on iPad all the links, all the images, are not showing.

I've already read on many forums about this common problem between iOs and interactive PDF's. But I have some old PDF's, with the same principle, and those are working great on iPad. The images are showed, the links works...

That's why I'm wondering if it's not my fault or maybe I export the PDF in a wrong way.

The links to the PDF's.

[m.hconline.eu/Baby%20Catalogue.pdf](http://m.hconline.eu/Baby%20Catalogue.pdf)

[m.hconline.eu/LA Catalog 2013.pdf](http://m.hconline.eu/LA%20Catalog%202013.pdf)

Comment: 1. You say that *have some old PDF's, with the same principle, and those are working great*; do those old PDFs use the same type of PDF form architecture as the new ones? I.e. both AcroForm or both Adobe XFA? ---
 2. Acroform form elements in an PDF can already have an appearance or can depend on the PDF viewer to create an appearance stream on the fly. Are the old and new PDFs identical in that respect? ---
 3. If neither item 1 nor item 2 nor anyone else's answer solves the problem, could you provide sample new and old PDF documents for inspection?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how to check the PDF form architecture. The old PDF's are made in InDesign CS2, with Adobe PDF Library 7.0, and mine is made in InDesign CS6, with Adobe PDF Library 10.0.1.

I don't have the original files for the old PDF's...

I've updated my original question with links to the PDF's. The old one is named Baby Catalogue, and the new one is LA Catalog 2013.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Please supply sample files

Comment: My question is now updated and the links to the files are working. Thank you.

Comment: Inspecting the files reveales that both times AcroForm is used and appearances are present. But if, as Librello states in his answer, the old file does not work on an iPad, either, there is no need to compare anymore... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Buttons" are not compatible with most pdf readers (except Acrobat reader and a few others). Such buttons are not recognized on the standard pdf reader on the iPad. I have checked the old file on the iPad, it does not work as well.

What you need to do is to use regular pdf links instead of buttons. In order to do so, you can use Acrobat Pro, delete your buttons, and create new links using the chain icon. You can specify the area of the link, so the user experience will be the same.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'll try to export the PDF without all the buttons and add them in Acrobat PRO.

Comment: Missing support for buttons in those readers is no good sign as buttons are part of ISO 32000-1, the PDF specification. That being said, @Honey-DavidCramariuc, replacing all those buttons manually may be a tedious task. If you prefer to do some development instead, many existing PDF libraries (in Java and .Net e.g. iText and iTextSharp) allow you to automatize the proposed replacment.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old issue, but I did find more information regarding this. (I'd add a comment to the accepted answer, but alas, i do not have 50 points.)

According to George Johnson, "The problem with InDesign is in using the Go To Next/Previous Page options in InDesign[buttons], it creates an Execute a Menu Item action when exported to PDF, and since Reader for iOS doesn’t have menu items or interprets such actions otherwise, they are just ignored." - https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1142056?tstart=0

As for work arounds, I found a tutorial by Steve Werner, outlining the method of changing your work flow around, and adding your buttons in Adobe Acrobat instead, as kind of a post production linking process. - http://indesignsecrets.com/navigation-button-tricks-for-interactive-pdf-on-an-ipad.php